# Stokes-Einstein's formula results in incorrect units for rotational drag coefficient

Tags: units, drag, fluctuation-dissipation

The [Stokes-Einstein-Sutherland relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_%28kinetic_theory%29), 
$$D = \frac{kT}{ 6 \pi \eta a}$$
where $D$ is the translational diffusivity is well known. A similar relationship is used to calculate the rotational diffusivity, specifically, 
$$D_{rot} = \frac{kT}{8 \pi \eta a^3},$$
where $a$ is the radius of the object and $\eta$ is the viscosity of the medium.

However, the drag coefficient in the denominator, $(8\pi\eta a^3)$ has units, $Js/rad$. But $D_{rot}$ has the units $rad^2/s$. Now $kT$ is in Joules, so does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

An angle in $rad$ is just a number and it is dimensionless. So drag coefficient has units $J.s$, $kT$ has units $J$ and $D_{rot}$ has units $s^{-1}$.